# The probability of maximum of two independent Poisson-distributed variables

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I have two Poisson distributions with parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ and two independent variables $A$ and $B$ from these two distributions. I know that

$$\begin{equation*}
\mathsf P(\min(A,B)>K)=\mathsf P(A>K) \ast \mathsf P(B>K)  
\end{equation*}$$

I'm just wondering what $\mathsf P(\max(A,B)>K)$ is. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the maximum of two numbers is greater than some constant, then either one or the other of the numbers is greater than it;   they are *not* both less than or equal to it.

If the random variables are independently Poisson distributed then:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(\max(A,B)>K) & =\mathsf P(A>K \cup B>K)
\\[1ex] & = 1 - \mathsf P(A\leq K)\mathsf P(B\leq K)
\\[1ex] & = 1 - \sum_{j=0}^K\frac{\lambda_1^j e^{-\lambda_1}}{j!}\;\sum_{j=0}^K\frac{\lambda_2^j e^{-\lambda_2}}{j!}
\\[1ex] & = 1 - \frac{\Gamma(K+1,\lambda_1)\Gamma(K+1,\lambda_2)}{K!^2}
\end{align}$$

---

$\Gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the [Incomplete Gamma Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html)

Comment: Thank you. Is this approach also true for more than two variables?

Comment: Both of the Answers are applicable to several independent random variables. This one for several independent Poisson random variables.

Answer (score 5):

Let $W = \max(A, B)$,
then $P(W > k) = 1 - P(W \le k) = 1 - P(A \le k)P(B \le k).$

Comment: I think $W$ became $X$ and $K$ became $k$. +1 anyway.

Comment: Right. Phone rang while proofing.